# Can a delim be used more than once for strtok in C?

Tags: c, strtok

Is there a way to use a delim more then once for strtok? I can only get the code to work for either load or init but not both. Example code in which strtok is used to token input from the user in the form of load # or init #,#,direction:

```
if ((tok = strtok(choice, " ")) && strcmp(tok, COMMAND_LOAD) == 0){
    tok = NULL;
    if((tok = strtok(tok, " ")) != NULL){
    /*some code*/
    }
}
else if((tok = strtok(choice, " ")) && strcmp(tok, COMMAND_INIT) == 0){
    tok = NULL;
    if((tok = strtok(tok, ",")) != NULL){
    /*some code*/
    }
}
```

Comment: If you set `tok` to `NULL` and then try to use it as a string, you're not going to get much. You can also do `tok = strtok(choice, " ")` once and then check `tok` in an if/else if.

Comment: @Schwern This is a correct usage. See *man strtok(3).*

Comment: @EJP Oh that's right, strtok is bonkers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `strtok` function is not reentrant, you can not use it for multiple simultaneously tokenizations.

Use [`strtok_s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) instead, if you have it. Or `strtok_r` is you have it.